# How can I subtract a value gotten from the loop

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code

```
// $res[] has two values(75000, 30000)
// $_SESSION['requestedAmt'] = 35000
while ($row = $queryWithdrawalTable->fetch_assoc()) {
    $res[] = $row['profit_amt'];
    foreach ($res as $amt) {
        if ($_SESSION['requestedAmt'] > $amt) {
            $calc = $_SESSION['requestedAmt'] - $amt;
        } else {
            $calc = $amt - $_SESSION['requestedAmt'];
        }
    }
    echo $calc; // outputs 5000 40000 
}
```

What I actually want to achieve is

```
$a[] = (1500, 3000);
$b = 2500;

while(fetch the data) {
  $res = $a - $b;
}
// output = 2000
```

I want the value in $b to subtract the first value in $a(1500) and use result gotten from the first calculation to subtract from the second value(3000). please note I'm new to programming so any suggestion will be accepted thanks guys.

I want to be able to assign a single user to pay multiple users. for example user1 has to pay $100 to user2($25), user3($50) and user4($25). I have user1 money in `$_SESSION['requestedAmt']` while the other users in `$row['profit_amt']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there, you only perform the calculation after you have all the value inside the `$res` array

```
while ($row = $queryWithdrawalTable->fetch_assoc()) {
    $res[] = $row['profit_amt'];
}

$calc = $_SESSION['requestedAmt'];
foreach ($res as $amt) {
    if ($_SESSION['requestedAmt'] > $amt) {
         $calc = $calc - $amt;
    } else {
         $calc = $amt - $calc;
    }
}

echo $calc;
```

Or you don't need the $res array at all, perform the calculation while fetching the rows:

```
$cals = $_SESSION['requestedAmt'];
while ($row = $queryWithdrawalTable->fetch_assoc()) {
    if ($_SESSION['requestedAmt'] > $row['profit_amt']) {
         $calc = $calc - $amt;
    } else {
         $calc = $amt - $calc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible for me to replace the subtraction with modulus

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve so I can't answer that. But in the context of syntax, you can do that.

Comment: I had to unchecked your answer because it's not giving me the desire result I want.

Comment: Do you mind adding more details about desired result to the question so I can improve my answer?

Comment: ok. I want to be able to assign a single user to pay multiple users. for example user1 has to pay $100 to user2($25), user3($50) and user4($25). I have user1 money in ```$_SESSION['requestedAmt']``` while the other users in ```$row['profit_amt']``` 
thanks @catcon